# Table Sync from DB2 to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a tables in Db2, That which we need to get that table to MS SQL server (only for read), And I want it to be in sync for every 15 minutes (one way from DB2 to SQL Server). Can you suggest the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

Have a SQL Agent job execute an SSIS package every 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I know that all the time MERGE is the right option to sync the tables in the SQL. But I am not sure, whether we can use it in linked servers also. Anyway, after some research I got this task accomplished by using the merge join. Merge will update, insert, delete what ever required. But it will take a little bit more time to update the table for every 15 min, when the job runs. So, you can create a #Temptable to insert the transactions that were done from the lastjob done.You can use the datetime stamp in that source table to retrieve the transactions that were done from the last job done(15min). If you don't have the date time in source table, you can use the audit table for that source table(if applicable).

(JLT table have 3 columns (last_job_end)( cur_job_start)(some job identity). JLT is the job log table we need to create in linked server to get the last job end and cur job start time, We need to update last job end every time at the end of query in JOB. As well as cur job start in the beginning of the job )

```
SELECT * 
INTO #TEMPtable 
FROM OPENQUERY([DB2], 'Select *  from source_table
                       where some_id_column in 
                            (select some_id_column  
                             from audit_table AT, Job_log_table  JLT
                             where datetime > last_job_end 
                               and datetime <= cur_job_start
                               and c_job = ''some_job_id'')’)`
```

If you don't have the audit table and you have the datetime in Source.

```
SELECT * 
INTO #TEMPtable 
FROM OPENQUERY([DB2], 'Select * 
                       from source_table s, JOB_CYCLE_TABLE pr
                       where s.DATETIME <= pr.cur_job_start 
                         and s.DATETIME > pr.last_job_end
                         and pr.c_job = ''some_job_id''')
```